# Search users with elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I try to search for users in elasticsearch. I have one user, "Andy" in the index. And when i search on "gujjghjhgj" i get one user(Andy) back from elasticsearch. Why? If no user was found, return nothing. How can i do this? I have this:

```
var ui = new UserInfo { UserName = "Andy", Name = "", UserNr = 1};
Client.CreateIndex("users");

Client.Update<UserInfo, UserInfo>
                (DocumentPath<UserInfo>
                    .Id(ui.UserNr), descriptor => descriptor.Doc(ui).DocAsUpsert().Refresh()
                );

var Result = Client.Search<UserInfo>(s => s
            .Index("users")
            .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Query(name)
            ))
            .Size(pageSize)
            .From((currentPage - 1)*pageSize));

unitItems = Result.Total;
return Result.Documents.ToList();

[Serializable, ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "UserNr")]
public class UserInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public int UserNr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does the mapping for `UserInfo` look like? Is it explicitly defined or inferred?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your search is that it does not specify a field to perform the `match` query on; the value to perform a match with is specified but not the field.

In this scenario, **[NEST's conditionless query logic](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/writing-queries.html#conditionless-queries)** (*note: this is old documentation, but conditionless queries apply to newer versions of NEST*) kicks in and because field does not have a value, the `match` query is not emitted as part of the search request. The request ends up looking like

```
POST http://localhost:9200/users/userinfo/_search 
{
    "from":0,
    "size":10
}
```

with the document with `UserNr` 1 returned.

To fix this, you just need to specify the field name. Here's a complete example to demonstrate

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        // Disabling direct streaming and logging out requests and responses
        // is useful during development, but may not want to do this
        // in production as it has performance implications.
        // Used here to write out requests and responses.
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .OnRequestCompleted(response =>
            {
                // log out the request
                if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                        $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                }

                // log out the response
                if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
            })
            .DefaultIndex("users");

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var ui = new UserInfo { UserName = "Andy", Name = "", UserNr = 1 };

    if (!client.IndexExists("users").Exists)
    {
        client.CreateIndex("users");
    }

    // can use index
    client.Index(ui, descriptor => descriptor.Refresh());

    var pageSize = 10;
    var currentPage = 1;
    var name = "gujjghjhgj";

    var searchResponse = client.Search<UserInfo>(s => s
        .Index("users")
        .Query(q => q
            .Match(m => m
                // specify the field 
                .Field(f => f.UserName)
                .Query(name)                
            )
        )
        .Size(pageSize)
        .From((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
    );

    var total = searchResponse.Total; 
    var docs = searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
}

[Serializable, ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "UserNr")]
public class UserInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public int UserNr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanx. But now when i search on "Andy" i get one user back, BUT when i search on "An" or "And" i get nothing back. Why? :(

Comment: That's best asked as a separate question :) In short, it's because the `UserName` property mapping will be using the standard analyzer by default so no `ngram` (or `edge ngram`) analysis is run on the input. Additionally, the `match` query will not perform prefix matching. To resolve, you can use a `prefix query` or, if you expect to do a lot of prefix matches, update the mapping to map `UserName` as a `multi_field` with different different types of analysis, and reindex your documents.

Comment: @mrcode Please open another question as this question is a new, different question.

Comment: @mrcode if my answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and, if it answers your question, feel free to mark as accepted :)